# Passing multiple request headers to libcurl.net

Tags: c#, ajax, cookies, curl, libcurl.net

I have recently started using libcurl.net with one of my projects as a replacement to the `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes. The reason I chose to use libcurl.net instead of the managed classes is that libcurl.net mimics the behavior of cURL from PHP and I was porting over some code from PHP. I attempted to use the built-in managed classes, but the `CookieContainer` class was not capturing all of the cookies correctly from the website that I was trying to capture cookies from. I may end up going back to the managed classes if I can figure out how to capture the cookies correctly.

My PHP script works perfectly fine in capturing cookies so I ported most of the cURL functionality using libcurl.net to my C# project. The problem I'm having is when I have to send more than one request header with the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` cURL option and I have to use an Slist datatype to pass in more than one header like so:

```
Slist headers = new Slist();
headers.Append("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
headers.Append("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest");
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

I sometimes have to fake an AJAX request but it does not seem to pass the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header with the request as the website I'm scraping does not return any results for these "fake" AJAX requests. If I set the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` do I need to set the `Content-Type` header or is that always defaulted to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was adding multiple headers correctly. I simply made an `Slist` object and added my headers to the request using the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option. In this way, one can "fake" AJAX requests or any other type of request sent by a web browser. The problem was that I wasn't sending the correct POST data with my request.